# JQUERY Get Element By parameter ID

Tags: jquery

just want to know what is the equivalent syntax of this to jquery.

```
var elm_id = 'my_id';
var elm = document.getElementById(elm_id);
```

thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you're looking for is

```
var elm_id = 'my_id';
var elm = $('#' + elm_id);
```

Answer (score 3):

Selecting by ID in jquery is done with the `#` character:

```
$('#my_id')
```

I invite you to read the documentation about **[jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**

Answer (score 3):

In jquery the following code is being written as:

```
var elm = $("#my_id");
```

OR you can write as:

```
var elm_id = 'my_id';
var elm = $("#" + elm_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var elm_id = 'my_id'; 
var elm = $('#' + elm_id)[0];
```

Adding the [0] gets the actual node which is what document.getElementById(elm_id); returns.

Comment: If you want the actual node, it would be `.get(0)`.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: .get(0) === [0]. Although get() can do a bit more I prefer the square brackets because it's shorter. See also http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: True. My mistake. For some reason, I remembered as if the simple array notation returned a jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks you TJ and BAZMEGAKAPA it works. I am just wondering, what does the code below returns. because this is my first attempt before posting here, it does return a value but what?

var elm_id = 'my_id';
var elm = $('#' + elm_id);

sorry i am new to jquery..
thanks.

Comment: In this case *elm* is a jQuery object which is an array of matched elements, in your case one. The matched elements include a reference to the node *and* additional jQuery functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You need this (I think):

```
$('#my_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var elem_id="my_id";
$("#"+elem_id);
```